# What's a good simple bitmap editor that run in a browser (jquery/java/javascript)?

Tags: java, javascript, browser, bitmap

I need to embbed a bitmap editor in one of my site pages. Is there a good option out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand your scope beyond javascript to include bitmap editors written in Flash, there are a few decent options.

For Javascript, have a look at [Pixlr](http://www.pixlr.com/wiki/developer/api/js-lib).

Answer (score 1):

Not embeddable but should get you started if you can't find anything else and have implement one yourself:

http://scriptar.com/images/bitmap.htm

http://www.amberfrog.com/product/bme/